# What's the difference between these two sentences? start vs get started

Tags: meaning, difference

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

- Roll up your sleeves. We're about to get started!
- Roll up your sleeves. We're about to start!

Comment: No, there is no difference in meaning.

Comment: Hi @KateBunting, which one are you more used to using?

Comment: Personally, I would consider "We're about to start" OR "Roll up your sleeves and we'll get started" more idiomatic.